# Ender's Game - Where to find author's introduction?

Tags: enders-game, orson-scott-card

I remember reading the author's introduction to *Ender's Game* where Orson Scott Card depicts his struggles with getting the book published.  He would bring the manuscript to publishers who would reject it saying it was awful.  He would then go back and rewrite the entire book from scratch.  Then, he would go back and get rejected again.  This happened for 15 years until he finally wrote a draft that was great.

This is a great lesson about how to produce great writing.  I would love to show it to my students.  I don't know if it was from this book or one of his interviews, but I remember reading it.  Can someone direct me to where I can find it?  (I've looked at several versions of the book.)

Comment: That is very interesting and what perseverance! Are you saying that the book itself lacks this intro? Surely the author has a website where perhaps this book is discussed or even there is contact info for OSC. But you have it sounds like captured the gist and you can encourage and/or scare the pants off of your students from what you seem to remember. But the actual intro would of course be of interest. Good luck.

Comment: I remember a very long intro in the 1991 (I think!) revised version of Ender's Game that touched on some of the issues about  getting it published, but it's about five years since I had a physical copy.

Comment: Hmmmm. The introduction written by Card for the 1988 edition doesn't deal with his trials in getting the manuscript rejected. It mostly talks about the backlash he got from his readers parents...

Comment: Ender's Game (Author's Definitive Edition) ISBN 0-8125-5070-6. is probably what you're after.

Comment: Are we talking about the novellette "Ender's Game" (published in *Analog* in 1977 when Card was 26) or the novel (1985, eight years later)?  Does one of these have "15 years" of rejections preceding it?

Comment: Maybe your confusing it with some other work of Card's? According to this [interview](https://youtu.be/xh3cMoQQ2h8?t=1724) he first came up with the Battleroom when he was 16 and after sitting on his idea for some 10 years he got it published as a short story just fine. A few years later he had a publishing deal for Speaker for the Dead but realized it would only work with Ender as the protagonist. So he decided to turn the short story into a prequel novel. The publisher immediately gave him a second book deal. So it doesn't seem like he had any trouble getting it published.

Comment: You can try asking OSC on his Hattrack River website.  It may take a while, but he does post answers to questions there.  If you do, please come back and share the answer with us!

Comment: Are you sure it was in an introduction? Card has written several books on how to write Science Fiction, so could the anecdote be in one of those? (And if so, possibly not even about his own work)

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help!  I might be wrong because it's been about 20 years.  I do believe it was Ender's Game but I know enough psychology to be wary of past memories.

I remember reading how he brought his first draft to his publisher who roundly dismissed it. He then showed his work to his wife, family, and friends who all helped him completely dismantle the story. When he brought it to his publisher, it got rejected again. He even admitted it was terrible.  But, over 15 years of constant draft, he finally created a great book.

Comment: What stood out to me at the time was that Card didn't go through this same process with his other books.  And, I always thought that shows the power of drafting because I always thought his other books weren't anything as good as Ender's Game.

I could have sworn it was Ender's Game.  But, I may be wrong.  Would anyone know what book it would be then?

Comment: It could be something else like an interview.  I've read several of his other books too.  I just got this vague sense that it's the intro.  Wow, this is maddening!

Comment: @QuietInMontana It sounds more like the intro to his fix up novel [The Worthing Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Worthing_Saga). In that Card describes how he wrote the first story _Tinker_ at age 19 and got it rejected, the rewrote it at age 24 and got it rejected again, then finally rewrote it as _The Worthing Chronicle_ that was eventually published 6 years later. If you go to [the Amazon listing here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Worthing-Saga-Orson-Scott-Card-ebook/dp/B0042FZW7A/) and click the _Read Sample_ button you can read the introduction in the sample.

Comment: Hi, John, I checked out The Worthing Saga and it's not that.  Maybe it wasn't Ender's Game.  It was 20 years ago so I might be thinking of a different book.  And, I read A LOT of different books back then.  I just remember the author saying how he had to almost REWRITE each draft from scratch.  He would ask many different people for help, which was important since it provided different points of view.  They would even disagree on many of the minutiae of how things worked like space travel.  Conversations like this evidently transformed the book.